# how to customize ng-bootstrap alert

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

it's the first time I use ng-bootstrap,
and I want to know how to customize an alert, I saw the example but it doesn't work for me

**This is my code**

app.component.html

```
<ngb-alert type="custom" [dismissible]="false"><strong>Whoa!</strong> This is a custom alert.</ngb-alert>
```

alert-custom.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-alert-custom',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [`
    :host >>> .alert-custom {
      color: #99004d;
      background-color: #f169b4;
      border-color: #800040;
    }
  `]
})
export class NgbdAlertCustom {}
```

alert-custom.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NgbdAlertCustom } from './alert-custom';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [NgbdAlertCustom],
  exports: [NgbdAlertCustom],
  bootstrap: [NgbdAlertCustom]
})
export class NgbdAlertCustomModule {}
```

main.ts

```
import './polyfills';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { NgbdAlertCustomModule } from "./app/NgbdAlertCustomModule";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(NgbdAlertCustomModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

when using this code you only see the text of the alert, without any decoration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to replicate the issue which you faced with the attached code...

Attached is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkfywy) which works with the code you provided

relevant **app.component.html**:

```
<ngb-alert type="custom" [dismissible]="false"><strong>Whoa!</strong> This is a custom alert.</ngb-alert>
```

relevant **alert-custom.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-alert-custom',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [`
    :host >>> .alert-custom {
      color: #99004d;
      background-color: #f169b4;
      border-color: #800040;
    }
  `]
})
export class NgbdAlertCustom {}
```

Comment: Is there any way to put two  **"platformBrowserDynamic (). bootstrapModule ()"**?,
since when I delete **"platformBrowserDynamic (). bootstrapModule (AppModule)"**
the page goes blank